# Django ignoring changes made to URLS.py file - Amazon AWS

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, http-status-code-404, django-urls

I just created an EC2 instance and created a Django app and am using Amazon servers. Normally when I make a change to my Djnago app, I updated it by doing

```
git add .
git commit -m "change"
git aws.push
```

I recently made changes to my URLS.py file and did the three steps above. I then went to my website and for some reason when I visit a URL, it gives a 404 not found error and says

```
Using the URLconf defined in myapp.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

    1. ^$

The current URL, register/, didn't match any of these.
```

However, my URLS.py does infact have

```
url(r'^$', mainPageView),
url(r'^login/$', login),
url(r'^logout/$', logoutView),
url(r'^register/$', registerView),
```

and many others. I even tried doing

```
eb update
```

just to see if that will updated the server but it does not. How come Django gives me a 404 error saying that the URL didn't match any of my URLS in my URLS.py file even though it does?

Comment: Did you restart the threads? can't say about Amazon, but changes in files other than templates require the django process to reload.

Comment: @petkostas hm, how do I restart the threads / reload the django process? Do you mean I should stop and start the server again?

Comment: yes, restart django server or whatever is running django code (uwsgi, gunicorn)

Comment: @petkostas I restarted the server but it still didn't work :/ It's giving the same 404 error even after I did 'eb stop' and 'eb start'

Comment: @user2719875 404 means the requested view was not found, which in turn does not suggest the problem is with urls.py (server restart though is required), debug your views and see where the problem lies, check in your local testing box.

Comment: @petkostas no but it says 'the current url dis not match any of these' and it only listed one url. Shouldn't it have listed all of the urls? That is why I believe that my urls.py file isn't being loaded properly, because in my urls.py file, the is a lot more than just one url

Comment: Are your urls inside urlpatterns?:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/http/urls/#example

Comment: @petkostas yup, they are. It's weird because even if I delete all the urls in urls.py and then restart the server and go accses my site, it still loads the main page of the site even though I remove all urls from urls.py. When I restart my server, it does in fact show that all the urls were deleted.

Comment: Is this urls.py your main urls.py? or are using a separate urls.py under an app? if it's not the main you have to include it. Also are you referring to Class Based Views? if yes then the syntax is not correct it should be `mainPageView.as_view()`

Comment: I assuming you are using the [EB CLI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-reference-eb.html), please [start an ssh connection to the machine](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-ssh.html) and provide in your question the contents of the `URLS.py` file on your AWS machine, by running `cat URLS.py` at the apropriate location.