# how to restart Django server without terminating database and server instance - AWS

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am hosting a Django application on AWS Elastic Beanstalk. I recently made changes to my URLS.py and apparently (according to this thread: [Django ignoring changes made to URLS.py file - Amazon AWS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25153129/django-ignoring-changes-made-to-urls-py-file-amazon-aws) ) I need to 'reload the django process / restart the thread'. I figured that meant for me to run

```
eb stop
```

and then

```
eb start
```

again but when I ran

```
eb stop
```

it needed to first terminate my database as well as my EC2 instance, cloudwatch alarm etc. Is there any way for me to restart the DJango process so that it can update the URLS.py file without me having to run

```
eb stop
eb start
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to stop and start your environment. From what I understand you need to update your environment with your updated source code. Did you try git commit folloed by git aws.push?
Take a look here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-reference-get-started.html

Let me know if you run into any issues with git aws.push.

You can also try restart app server on your environment using aws cli: 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elasticbeanstalk/restart-app-server.html
But as far as I can tell, git aws.push will suffice.

Comment: for some reason, hit aws.push is not working. I also just did eb stop and eb start and it still didn't update the urls.py file. Is there any way to update the source code manually?

Comment: also, for the second link which you provided (restart-app-server), how exactly do I do it? I tried typing 'restart-app-server' as well as 'elastic-beanstalk-restart-app-server' as well as 'eb restart-app-sever' and none of those commands were found.

Comment: I would not recommend updating the source code manually, although you can ssh to the EC2 instance and look for the source code in the /opt/elasticbeanstalk directory to see if your updated urls.py file is present or not. git add urls.py; git commit -a; git aws.push; should push the latest code to your instances. Can you log on the AWS Web console and check if there are any errors in the events? Make sure you select the right region when looking for the environment. You can restart app server from the web console or the AWS CLI. http://aws.amazon.com/cli/

Comment: eb stop and eb start will create a whole new environment from scratch so you might want to double check your urls.py setup? e.g. Does you django app work on localhost?

Comment: it works perfectly on localhost. It's weird because I just deleted everything from urls.py and did 'git add .' 'git commit' and 'git aws.push' and it did say that all the lines in urls.py were deleted. I then went back to the url and for some reason, it still somehow loaded my main page of the app even though I deleted everything from my urls.py. It seems as if it is using another urls.py. When it gives the 404 error (when I access another url other than the main page of the app), it says that it searches 'myapp/urls.py' and that is the exact file which I deleted everything.

Comment: Strange. I would recommend downloading your app source using the web console and seeing what is actually deployed. You can also ssh to the instance to see the actual contents of urls.py.

Comment: To download your most recent app source from the web console find your environment in the web ui, then click on Upload and Deploy, then click on All versions, find the deployed version and download the zip file.

Comment: ah, okay now we're getting somewhere. For some reason, in the urls.py of the deployed version, there is only one url in the url pattern, which is the main page. When I looked at all the versions, there were in fact more recent versions than the deployed version but they were just not deployed. Any idea why the more recent versions are not becoming the 'deployed version' even though I doing 'git add .' 'git commit -m "made changes to urls' and 'git aws.push'? It even gives a success message after I do git aws.push

Comment: That can happen when the deployment fails on the instance. You can look at events for your environment in the web console. There is also an API called DescribeEvents to do that. But for now I think you can just use Web Console as it is convenient. Just go to the same screen where you found the Upload And Deploy button. There will be events below it. Click on Show All and you may be able to see error events if any.

Comment: Snapshot logs also help in these scenarios for debugging. Give this a try: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.loggingS3.title.html

Comment: hm, it says "Return code: 1 Output: Error occurred during build: Command 01_syncdb failed" and "Update environment operation is complete, but with errors. For more information, see troubleshooting documentation." I checked my error log in the snapshot logs and the last error was yesterday saying "SuspiciousOperation: Invalid HTTP_HOST header (you may need to set ALLOWED_HOSTS)" but that was nearly 24 hours ago. My ALLOWED_HOSTS is empty in my settings.py file because the only thing which is hosting the app is the amazon server so it should work normally right?

Comment: also, now when I look at the most recent app source code, the urls.py is updated and has all the urls but it seems as if the server doesn't want to use this. I'm guessing because I first need to solve the 'syncdb failed' error first?

Comment: you are correct, git add / git aws.push is enough and I did not need to do eb stop and eb start. The reason my urls weren't loading was because I was having a syncdb error. By using the error logs and the events in my environment which were shown in the web console, I managed to figure out the issue. Nonetheless, git  commit followed by git aws.push is enough to restart the Django server.

Answer (score 0):

I've had troubles with my Django files not updating after using:

```
$ eb deploy
```

The eb cli tool does not have a restart command, however you can login to the AWS console and restart your environment through the actions menu on the dashboard for your eb environment.

This generally fixes any issues that I have. However sometimes I've had to ssh directly into the instance and enable debugging through the settings.

The other command that Rohit referenced is from a different aws cli tool. I haven't personally tried it but here is more documentation on the command and how to install it:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/installing.html