# Aws not detect urls.py file in django?

Tags: python, mysql, django, amazon-web-services, nginx

I made changes in a **urls.py** in my application but **AWS EC2** showing page not found error , I restarted server several time but still I get same result .

I am using **Nginx** + **gunicorn** + **MySQL** + **Django** on AWS . I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25153129/django-ignoring-changes-made-to-urls-py-file-amazon-aws) on StackOverflow but not answered by anyone .

[image]

## urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls.static import static
import settings
from collapp.views import get_branch, get_college, get_course, get_university, get_department, signup, login, \
    email_exist, forget_password, change_password, username_exist, get_newsfeed

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^exist/email/(?P<email_id>[\w.%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})/$', email_exist),
    url(r'^exist/username/(?P<username>[\w\W]+)/$', username_exist),
    url(r'^forgot/email/(?P<email_id>[\w.%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})/$', forget_password),
    url(r'^change/password/(?P<email_id>[\w.%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})/$', change_password),
    url(r'^newsfeed/$', get_newsfeed)
]
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Helpful suggestion will be appreciated .

Comment: The URLs listed on the error page don't match what's in your `urls.py` file.  Also the debug page says it's using `colledge.urls`, which you do not mention anywhere.  What is the value of `ROOT_URLCONF` in your `settings.py`1file?

Comment: @JohnGordon ROOT_URLCONF = 'colledge.urls' and i change urls.py content but it shows previous urls file .

Comment: colledge/urls.py file

Comment: Did you restart the webserver once you deployed the change?

Comment: @DanielRoseman i have restarted server several times .

Comment: Is the `urls.py` file listed in your question actually `colledge/urls.py`?

Comment: @JohnGordon yes